# 3rd Gear Popping Out

Tags: mazda, manual-transmission

I'm currently driving a 2006 Mazda 3 and my 3rd gear has worked with no issues since i bought the car in 2006, but a couple days ago my 3rd gear would randomly pop out while I was driving in it and at other times it will be fine. I have not taken to a mechanic yet, but that is in the works. I'm more interested to know if it is a Transmission problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Ive had this happen to me with the reverse gear. I took it to a mechanic and learnt it would require a rebuild or replacement from a wrecked car (careful the replacements not damaged from the any crashes). Sorry, its not an easy issue to fix...

Answer (score 1):

LOL - yeah, it's a transmission problem. If you want to just hold it in 3rd gear until it's time to shift to 4th, it will never hurt anything. But, you're looking at a transmission rebuild to fix it.